# Precompile Error Rake Aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm having a trouble getting my application to render on Heroku. Here are the details:

After the command:
    **git push heroku master**

[image]

I run **heroku logs**:

[image]

I'm doing my homework on precompile errors, but I'm certain that I don't really *understand* the error to deduce a solution -- guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your application.css file?

Comment: Kobaltz thanks for the response. Here are the contents:http://snippi.com/s/9n07ehd

Comment: It's referencing to other CSS Styling your assets directory. Can you post those as well?

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/gjg1nkm -- user.css.scss

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/29sv1vg - style3.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check your application.css file. You have some styling in there that is not correct. When heroku tried to compile the assets, it ran into the error.

Line 80 of your style3.css has an extra comma in it. Also, you've declared `body` twice. However, the `body` twice shouldn't generate the error, but it would be overwriting the previous entry.

Honestly, over 3000 lines is kind of crazy. you may want to split this up into different sections. At line 3000 (not sure if it's a limitation of Snippi or if you've didn't finish the tag) you're missing the end `}` on the tag.

Comment: The unusual part about this is that the application.css is entirely commented. http://snippi.com/s/9n07ehd

Comment: Its just a limitation of snippi it seems. I've removed the extra comma, pushed the changes to heroku, but I'm the app still fails to render. I'm going to split the css up into sections as suggested.

Comment: The failure occurs on precompile it seems:  http://snippi.com/s/yi0vs93    I can't access the file in /tmp as designated in the error however... I'm going to attack this with fresh eyes tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I resolved the issue by removing a stray char at the end of the CSS